# Is it possible to use a column value as the argument to a hypothetical-set aggregate function?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

Say I have a table like the one described below.

```
                                     Table "public.foo"
  Column   |            Type             |                    Modifiers                 
-----------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer                     | not null default nextval('foo_id_seq'::regclass)
 data      | text                        | not null
 score     | integer                     |
```

To calculate the `percentile rank` for a particular score, I can do something like this:

```
test=# select percent_rank(5) within group (order by score) as rank from foo;
        rank     
--------------------
 0.0762917366163029
(1 row)
```

What I'd really like to do is have a select statement that shows the data, score, and rank for each row present. I tried the below query.

```
test=# select data, score, percent_rank(score) within group (order by score) as rank from foo group by data, score;
```

This produces a `rank` of **0** for every row. I'm *assuming* this is because the `within group` clause ends up being limited by `group by` clause, but I'm not enough of a SQL ninja to know for sure.

At any rate, is it possible to include the `percentile rank` of a row's score as part of a multi-row select?

Answer (score -1):

If you include ID I would assume that you can join it back to itself on ID to get that information in one dataset.

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example? The `data` column is the table's *unique* column...